# How to use volumes package

Tags: packages, include

I want to separate my book into different volumes, I searched this site and there is no satisfactory solution. I tried to work around with a package called volumes

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/volumes/volumes.pdf

However, after reading the manual, I still have no idea about how to use it, so can anyone just give me a concrete and compilable example.

Comment: I think [xr package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) is better for separete volumes

Answer (score 4):

The key part is getting the file names right, and compiling correctly. A minimal example looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{volumes is fun}
\author{me}

\usepackage{volumes}    
\volumename{chapter}

\begin{document} 
    \input{frontmatter}
    \include{chapter1}
    \include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

with the following additional files: `frontmatter.tex`

```
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
```

and `chapter1.tex`:

```
\chapter{one}
\lipsum[1]
```

and `chapter2.tex`:

```
\chapter{two}
\lipsum[2]
```

The `volumes` package only works on `\include`'s, thus, to always include the `frontmatter.tex`, we use `\input` instead. Then, as our files are called `chapterX.tex`, the `\volumename` must be set to `chapter`.

About compiling: First, you have to compile the document as usual. That way, all chapters are typeset and included. So far, the `volumes` package doesn't do much (if anything...). Now, that the relevant information on the document (page numbers, ...) is saved in the `.aux` files, you can exclude the parts you want. You can do that by adding e.g.

```
\onlyvolume[2]
```

*before* the `\begin{document}`. Now, simply recompile the document, and Chapter 1 will be excluded.

Comment: That's the 6th line (1st line of the second paragraph). I chose to put `\usepackage{volumes}` and `\volumename{..}` into a separate paragraph, to highlight separate them a bit from the "normal" stuff.

Comment: Sorry hbaderts.  My bad